# Parsing an expression grammar having function application with parser combinators (left-recursion)

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, recursive-descent, uu-parsinglib

As a simplified subproblem of a parser for a real language, I am trying to implement a parser for expressions of a fictional language which looks similar to standard imperative languages (like Python, JavaScript, and so). Its syntax features the following construct:

- integer numbers
- identifiers (`[a-zA-Z]+`)
- arithmetic expressions with `+` and `*` and parenthesis
- structure access with `.` (eg `foo.bar.buz`)
- tuples (eg `(1, foo, bar.buz)`) (to remove ambiguity one-tuples are written as `(x,)`)
- function application (eg `foo(1, bar, buz())`)
- functions are first class so they can also be returned from other functions and directly be applied (eg `foo()()` is legal because `foo()` might return a function)

So a fairly complex program in this language is

```
(1+2*3, f(4,5,6)(bar) + qux.quux()().quuux)
```

the associativity is supposed to be

```
( (1+(2*3)), ( ((f(4,5,6))(bar)) + ((((qux.quux)())()).quuux) ) )
```

I'm currently using the very nice [`uu-parsinglib`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib) an applicative parser combinator library.

The first problem was obviously that the intuitive expression grammar (`expr -> identifier | number | expr * expr | expr + expr | (expr)` is left-recursive. But I could solve that problem using the the `pChainl` combinator (see `parseExpr` in the example below).

The remaining problem (hence this question) is function application with functions returned from other functions (`f()()`). Again, the grammar is left recursive `expr -> fun-call | ...; fun-call -> expr ( parameter-list )`. Any ideas how I can solve this problem elegantly using `uu-parsinglib`? (the problem should directly apply to `parsec`, `attoparsec` and other parser combinators as well I guess).

See below my current version of the program. It works well but function application is only working on identifiers to remove the left-recursion:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
 {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

 module TestExprGrammar
     (
     ) where

 import Data.Foldable (asum)
 import Data.List (intercalate)
 import Text.ParserCombinators.UU
 import Text.ParserCombinators.UU.Utils
 import Text.ParserCombinators.UU.BasicInstances

 data Node =
     NumberLiteral Integer
     | Identifier String
     | Tuple [Node]
     | MemberAccess Node Node
     | FunctionCall Node [Node]
     | BinaryOperation String Node Node

 parseFunctionCall :: Parser Node
 parseFunctionCall =
     FunctionCall <$>
         parseIdentifier {- `parseExpr' would be correct but left-recursive -}
         <*> parseParenthesisedNodeList 0

 operators :: [[(Char, Node -> Node -> Node)]]
 operators = [ [('+', BinaryOperation "+")]
             , [('*' , BinaryOperation "*")]
             , [('.', MemberAccess)]
             ]

 samePrio :: [(Char, Node -> Node -> Node)] -> Parser (Node -> Node -> Node)
 samePrio ops = asum [op <$ pSym c <* pSpaces | (c, op) <- ops]

 parseExpr :: Parser Node
 parseExpr =
     foldr pChainl
           (parseIdentifier
           <|> parseNumber
           <|> parseTuple
           <|> parseFunctionCall
           <|> pParens parseExpr
           )
           (map samePrio operators)

 parseNodeList :: Int -> Parser [Node]
 parseNodeList n =
     case n of
       _ | n < 0 -> parseNodeList 0
       0 -> pListSep (pSymbol ",") parseExpr
       n -> (:) <$>
           parseExpr
           <* pSymbol ","
           <*> parseNodeList (n-1)

 parseParenthesisedNodeList :: Int -> Parser [Node]
 parseParenthesisedNodeList n = pParens (parseNodeList n)

 parseIdentifier :: Parser Node
 parseIdentifier = Identifier <$> pSome pLetter <* pSpaces

 parseNumber :: Parser Node
 parseNumber = NumberLiteral <$> pNatural

 parseTuple :: Parser Node
 parseTuple =
     Tuple <$> parseParenthesisedNodeList 1
     <|> Tuple [] <$ pSymbol "()"

 instance Show Node where
     show n =
         let showNodeList ns = intercalate ", " (map show ns)
             showParenthesisedNodeList ns = "(" ++ showNodeList ns ++ ")"
         in case n of
              Identifier i -> i
              Tuple ns -> showParenthesisedNodeList ns
              NumberLiteral n -> show n
              FunctionCall f args -> show f ++ showParenthesisedNodeList args
              MemberAccess f g -> show f ++ "." ++ show g
              BinaryOperation op l r -> "(" ++ show l ++ op ++ show r ++ ")"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking briefly at [the list-like combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib-2.8.1.1/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-UU-Derived.html) for `uu-parsinglib` (I'm more familiar with `parsec`), I think you can solve this by folding over the result of the `pSome` combinator:

```
 parseFunctionCall :: Parser Node
 parseFunctionCall =
     foldl' FunctionCall <$>
         parseIdentifier {- `parseExpr' would be correct but left-recursive -}
         <*> pSome (parseParenthesisedNodeList 0)
```

This is also equivalent to the `Alternative` [`some`](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Control-Applicative.html#g:2) combinator, which should indeed apply to the other parsing libs you mentioned.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, that's very elegant and easy and works fine!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know this library but can show you how to remove left recursion. The standard right recursive expression grammar is

```
E -> T E'
E' -> + TE'  |  eps
T -> F T'
T' -> * FT'  |  eps
F -> NUMBER | ID | ( E )
```

To add function application you must decide its level of precedence. In most languages I've seen it is highest.  So you'd add another layer of productions for function application.

```
E -> T E'
E' -> + TE'  |  eps
T -> AT'
T' -> * A T' |  eps
A -> F A'
A' -> ( E ) A' | eps
F -> NUMBER | ID | ( E )
```

Yes this is a hairy-looking grammar and bigger than the left recursive one. That's the price of top-down predictive parsing. If you want simpler grammars use a bottom up parser generator a la yacc.

Comment: Thanks @Gene! I did actually not mention that in my question but I was trying to get around left factoring as it's not very elegant, is a lot of work and makes building the AST harder. Therefore I was quite happy about the `pChainl` combinator which solves the problem for operators (but not function application). But maybe there isn't actually an easy and elegant solution and I would have to left factor the whole grammar :-\. I might also just switch to the `happy` parser generator which is like yacc.